# How do I export a variable in react native that is being initialized within an onPress function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```js
//Journal.js

//...

let num;

const onPress = async() => {

// code gives num a value
    num = 2

}
//...

export num;
export defualt Journal;
```

```js
//Analysis.js


import {num} from './Journal';
//...

const someVar = num;
```

To my knowledge, it seems the Analysis page builds before the the user can select the OnPress function. When the OnPress function is pressed, Javascript doesnt rexport the variable num that needs to be used in Analysis. How do I utilize the updated value of num (which is updated after the onPress function is pressed in the Journal.js) in Analysis.js?

Comment: Updating a variable at a later time won't change the value exported. What is your use-case?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on what you mean by use-case?

Comment: What do you need the variable for? There's probably a better way to do what you want to do

Comment: So when the button is pressed, an API that analyzes some text the user has input is called. Based on what the user has input, a number between 0-5 is returned that corresponds to a different mood that the user is feeling, and "num" stores the value that is returned. The screen navigates to the Analysis page which displays the user's mood (based on the value of num) after the button is pressed but the journal page doesn't export the value of "num" post pressing the button and calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be storing `num` in some central state (eg redux) or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

For example

```jsx
// contexts/mood.js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const MoodContext = createContext({ num: null, setNum: () => {} });

const MoodContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState();

  return (
    <MoodContext.Provider value={{ num, setNum }}>
      {children}
    </MoodContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { MoodContext, MoodContextProvider };
```

You can then write a custom hook to use this context and expose your *analysis* functionality.

```js
// hooks/mood-analysis.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MoodContext } from "../contexts/mood";

const useMoodAnalysis = () => {
  const { setNum } = useContext(MoodContext);

  return async (inputValue) => {
    // ...
    setNum(2);
  };
};
```

All that's left is to wrap your components in the provider...

```jsx
<MoodContextProvider>
  <Routes>
    {/* ... just an example ... */}
  </Routes>
</MoodContextProvider>
```

use the hook in your `Journal` component...

```jsx
const analyse = useMoodAnalysis();

const onPress = async () => {
  // ...
  await analyse(someInputValue);
};
```

and read the context value in your `Analysis` component

```jsx
const { num } = useContext(MoodContext);
```